# Openssl RSA remove PEM password shows error

Tags: openssl

I am trying to remove PEM password from my pem file using this command:

```
openssl rsa -in "client-key.pem" -out "client-keyyyy.pem"
```

I get this output:

```
unable to load Private Key
14228:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:.\crypto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:142:
14228:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1303:
14228:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509_SIG
14228:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:.\crypto\pem\pem_pkey.c:125:
```

Here is my client-key.pm file

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am currently using OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009. Anyone knows what is this issue and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: **Your file is wrong or damaged.** The part of your file that should be base64 contains characters like `<N@&!*()` and `&*Q#&` that are not valid in base64 and thus PEM, and even if these were replaced by valid chars the total length is less than required by the outermost header (_if_ that part of the data is correct which it might not be); _no_ version of OpenSSL or anything else can read this file. You need to get the original file or a correct undamaged copy.

Comment: Hi sorry, I have forgotten to mention that I changed some characters for masking the content. The actual file does not contain special characters. @dave_thompson_085. I have edited the content to match correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this is not programming or development, but I need formatting. I agree to deletion if necessary.

Okay, your corrected file does parse, and it uses PBES2 encryption with HmacSHA256 in the KDF:

```
openssl asn1parse -i <75540200.pem
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1308 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  78 cons:  SEQUENCE
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :PBES2
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=  65 cons:   SEQUENCE
   19:d=3  hl=2 l=  41 cons:    SEQUENCE
   21:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :PBKDF2
   32:d=4  hl=2 l=  28 cons:     SEQUENCE
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:524158C67493974F
   44:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim:      INTEGER           :0800
   48:d=5  hl=2 l=  12 cons:      SEQUENCE
   50:d=6  hl=2 l=   8 prim:       OBJECT            :hmacWithSHA256
   60:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim:       NULL
   62:d=3  hl=2 l=  20 cons:    SEQUENCE
   64:d=4  hl=2 l=   8 prim:     OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc
   74:d=4  hl=2 l=   8 prim:     OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:6AA1D9643AE80A3D
   84:d=1  hl=4 l=1224 prim:  OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:[redacted]
```

Quite a few systems and programs have started doing this recently after SHA1 was broken for collision in 2017 (although the collision break doesn't actually make it vulnerable in KDF).

I no longer have a runnable 0.9.8k, but on my oldest test system I have 0.9.8m and 0.9.8zh (the last public release below 1.0.0), and both of them give a different and more specific error:

```
4890:error:0607607D:digital envelope routines:PKCS5_v2_PBE_keyivgen:unsupported prf:p5_crpt2.c:230:
4890:error:06074078:digital envelope routines:EVP_PBE_CipherInit:keygen failure:evp_pbe.c:101:
4890:error:23077073:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt:pkcs12 algor cipherinit error:p12_decr.c:83:
4890:error:2306A075:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:pkcs12 pbe crypt error:p12_decr.c:123:
4890:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:125:
```

Observe 'unsupported prf' -- 0.9.8 doesn't support PBKDF2 with a prf other than the default HmacSHA1. **You need to use at least 1.0.0** (and currently only 1.1.1 and 3.0.x are supported upstream, with 3.1.x coming soon), **or change whatever process generated the file** to not use HmacSHA256.